# How to read data from 2 collections and save data from both collection and save it in 3rd collection in SpringBatch

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am using springbatch to read data from mongo db using MongoItemReader bean.Suppose i want to read data from 2 different collections in a same job instance.Is this possible?

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public MongoItemReader<Object> reader() throws UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, Exception {
    DataReader dataReader = new DataReader();
    return dataReader.read();
}

@Bean
public DataItemProcessor processor() {
    return new DataItemProcessor();
}

@Bean
public MongoItemWriter<DestinationCollectionModelClass> writer() {
    MongoItemWriter<DestinationCollectionModelClass> writer = new MongoItemWriter<>();
    writer.setCollection("collection_name_where_data_is_saved");
    writer.setTemplate(mongoTemplate);
    return writer;
}

@Bean
public Step step1(MongoItemWriter<DestinationModelClass> writer) throws UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, Exception {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            // TODO: P3 chunk size configurable
            .<Object, DestinationModelClass>chunk(100)
            .reader(dataReader())
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer())
            .build();

}
```

Below is my class DataReader.java

public class DataReader extends MongoItemReader {

```
@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

@Override
public MongoItemReader<Object> read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException {

    List<Object> mongoItemReaderList = new ArrayList<>();

    Map<String, Direction> sorts = new HashMap<>();
    sorts.put("_id", Direction.ASC);
    

    MongoItemReader<Object> collectionOneReader = new MongoItemReader<>();
    collectionOneReader.setTemplate(mongoTemplate);
    collectionOneReader.setTargetType(CollectionOneModelClass.class);
    collectionOneReader.setQuery("{}");
    collectionOneReader.setSort(sorts);
    
    MongoItemReader<Object> collectionTwoReader = new MongoItemReader<>();
    collectionTwoReader.setTemplate(mongoTemplate);
    collectionTwoReader.setTargetType(CollectionTwoModelClass.class);
    collectionTwoReader.setQuery("{}");
    collectionTwoReader.setSort(sorts);

    mongoItemReaderList.add(collectionOneReader);
    mongoItemReaderList.add(collectionTwoReader);

    MongoItemReader<Object> readerObject =  (MongoItemReader<Object>) mongoItemReaderList;
    return readerObject;
}
```

}

Below is my DataItemProcessor.java

public class DataItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Object, DestinationModelClass> {

```
public DataItemProcessor() {}

@Override
public DestinationModelClass process(Object phi) throws Exception {
    DestinationModelClass hbd = new DestinationModelClass();
    if(phi instanceof CollectionOneModelClass) {
        //Processing code if Object is an instance of CollectionOneModelClass
    }
    
    if(phi instanceof CollectionTwoModelClass) {
        //Processing code if Object is an instance of CollectionTwoModelClass
    }
    return hbd;
}
```

}

Comment: How would you do that *without* Spring Batch? Please share your code for that. Are you planning to "join" two collections? How would you define an item in that case?

Comment: i dont want to join the collections .in my processor i will use some properties of collection1 and some properties of collection2  and save in 3rd collection.I am editing my question and adding my code snippet

Comment: Please first explain your problem with an example before sharing your attempted solution.

Comment: Problem is i need to read data from 2 different collections and process them and use some data from both collection and save it in third collection

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two readers in the same chunk-oriented step. What you can do is use the [driving query pattern](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/common-patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders), which, in your case, could be implemented as follows:

- Item Reader: reads items from collection 1
- Item Processor: enriches items from collection 2
- Item Writer: writes enriched items to collection 3

Comment: Thanks @Mahmoud Ben Hassine ,i will check the link.

Comment: I achieved my requirement by creating a view in Mongo query .I am creating view using aggregate query -$lookup –